# New tag - large-data

Tags: tags

A number of questions concern plotting/analysing large data sets. Therefore, it seems sensible to have a "large-data" tag. However, I don't like this name.

Any suggestions for a better name - or is "large-data" OK?

---

**Update**

I've started tagging questions with the "large-data" tag.

Comment: I kinda want to retag your post with a "tag-suggestion" new tag...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One important consideration is that the OP should easily be able to find appropriate tags when posting their question.  The current interface is a text input box that performs a real-time prefix search of the tags.  When someone is concerned about a large dataset, what might they start typing to find appropriate tags?  Not "high-dimensional," I don't think!  The prefix ought to be "large" or "big"--something simple like that.  But that presumes the tag system uses prefixes as modifiers.

Alternatively, create a set of tags that modify the word "data" with *suffixes*.  In this scheme, an OP concerned specifically about data might type the word "data" to produce a short list of data-related tags, such as "database", "database-large", "database-high-dimensional", "data-format", etc., allowing them to choose appropriately from this list.

Comment: I personally assume that they'll be prefixes - if I were trying to tag a question of this nature, "big-" would be my first attempt.

Comment: I like the idea of suffixes, but it seems strange for some tags. For example, data-discrete, transformation-data, data-missing..

Comment: I still haven't figured out how the synonyms work in practice.  Would it be effective to make the suffix form of a tag a synonym of its prefix form?  In particular, if we have a tag like discrete-data with a synonym data-discrete, then when a user types "data" in the tag search form, will it turn up "discrete-data"?

Comment: Great idea! Use synonyms. To answer your question about how it works, play about with *books* and it's synonym *textbook* You can tag a question *textbook* and search for [textbook](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books) and it will automatically get converted to *books*

Answer (score 5):

I think "large-data" is good.  I might have suggested "big-data", but that tends to mean explicitly data that cannot be kept in memory and/or must be dispersed (e.g. MapReduce).

Comment: I like big data, which I think extends to this question:  e.g. see the wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_data

Comment: @ars That was my first inclination, but I tend to think of it as having a specific meaning very large data; maybe propose it as a separate answer so people can vote on it?

Answer (score 2):

"big-data"

... for voting purposes.  This is my preference, but it doesn't have the same bigger-than-memory connotation for me as it does for Shane, so best to put it to the collective mind...

Answer (score 0):

What about just "big-n"?  One could also envision related tags "big-p-small-n" & "big-n-small-p" -- not that the latter would be used all that much.

Answer (score -1):

"high-dimensional-data" ?

Comment: I tend to think of "large data" as referring to a big sample, and "high dimensional" as a reference to a large number of variables, irrespective of sample size.  I could certainly be wrong, though.

Comment: @Matt You're right, esp. for the precision "irrespective of sample size" (it applies to omics data, neuroimaging data, etc.). Then, I think it raises an interesting issue about scoping, and we should try to address both kind of configuration (huge sample or n<<p case) -- for the moment, I have no better idea :)